# X-axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've written a simple program in Python using Matplotlib to draw lines in a coordinate system. I want X-Axis description to be "2006, 2007, 2008" but instead is shows as 
"0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2.0     +2.006e3"

code is here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot

import numpy as np

fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()

a=[2006,2007,2008]

b=[-1,3,5]

matplotlib.pyplot.plot(a, b, 'go-', label='line 1', linewidth=2)

matplotlib.pyplot.axis([2006, 2008, -1, 5])

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: This looks like your x-axis might be dates.  If they are, you might look into `plot_date()` and its cousins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
plt.axis([2006, 2008, -1, 5])
```

use [plt.xticks](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks):

```
plt.xticks(a, map(str,a))
```

---

PS: Its convenient to import `matplotlib.pyplot` with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

as this cuts down on the typing.